# DNS CNAME pushed from somewhere

Tags: dns, soa, cloudflare, mail-server

i have a mail server behind CloudFlare and when i check some logs and other DNS tools i seen a MX dc-abefc4aaxxxxx that isn't registered in my dns configuration in cloudflare. I tryed checking SOA and always shows cloudflare's name servers.
How can i really see where is this register being pushed?

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved this issue. Ocurrs when A record to Mail server is proxied and MX not. To solve this unproxy A record.

Here is the solution
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020296512-DNS-Troubleshooting-FAQ